# How to remove post page number in the URL

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I am using Wordpress, and wordpress has this function to let you separate a single posts into multiple pages.

The issue that I am having now is that when the user nagivates to page 2, the URL will become www.domain.com/post-title/2/ instead of staying at www.domain.com/domain-title/

Just to clarify, since I used the nextpage shortcode in my longer posts, so for 1 post, I would have say...a couple of pages like:

`http://www.domain.com/post1/
http://www.domain.com/post1/1/
http://www.domain.com/post1/2/
http://www.domain.com/post1/3/`

and I want it to just read http://www.domain.com/post1/ no matter on which post page.

I am using Nginx btw. Thanks!

Comment: did you tried changing the permalinks?

Comment: This may be better to post in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

here's my nginx wordpress configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
        server_tokens   off;
        root /path/to/root;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;
        index index.php;
        charset utf-8;
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        }
        location ~ \.php {
                include fastcgi_params;
                # change according to ur sock/port 
                fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Then go to permalink configuration page `http://domain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and change your permalink settings

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I was asking. My permalinks is working, means I will already get URLs like www.domain.com/post-title. However, the problem is that if I split my posts into pages, it'll show the page number, and I don't want that.

Comment: you want to be on the second page, without showing the `2` in the url ?

Comment: That is correct. Since users will share my post when they're on page 2, and the people who see the link will arrive on page 2. Rather weird isn't it? :)

Comment: well, the thing is, the server won't know which page you are on without that page number, do you use your own share buttons ? you can try configuring those.

Comment: Well it's just a rewrite no? I mean, so it'll still load www.domain.com/page-title/2, but then it shows www.domain.com/page-title in the address bar. I guess it'd be more of a nginx play, but I'm super bad w/ rewrite regex :-/

Comment: no no, think of it like this `http://domain/blog-post` can you guess what page I want? page 1 or 2 or 3? well so does the server, it doesn't know

Comment: I mean, if you used htaccess, you can rewrite the URL, just from the user's point of view. The system knows it's page-titie/2. It's just how wordpress has the permalinks, where it rewrites the URL w/ the page title, while the system would be receiving different parameters.

Comment: actually htaccess is quite the opposite, like you visit `page.html` and i tell the server to pretend its `page.php`, the opposite is not possible, you can't do a rewrite that apply's to the user side.

Comment: if we're talking about facebook share and stuff like that, you can add meta tags, like `og:url` for facebook that specifies the URL to share